# Google Spreadsheet Loop & IF statement: Loop through co-worker list and add them to a rotation schedule

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

EDIT - SOLVED

I have to make a rotation schedule for coworkers for the next year. Some coworkers have standard days off and I do not want to schedule them on those days.

This is the manual outcome I would like to get.

Example: Consultant A does not work on mondays, so I do not want Consultant A to be added to the schedule on a monday.
I then want consultant B to be added to the schedule as a fill-up. Consultant A would be next in line on a tuesday etc. Next would be consultant C but consultant C does not work on wednesdays. Therefore, we need to take consultant D for wednesday and consultant C on a thursday, and so on. When we are at the last consultant of the F column, it needs to start again at consultant A.

[image: Manual Outcome]

I have tried all kinds of formulas, like if statements and arrayformula. But there is no way that I know of to loop through the F column just with formulas.

I am not sure if this is at all clear what I want to achieve here, I am stuck

I am using additionally an add-on to send the schedule to everyone's agenda, thats also the reason why i'd love to automate this, because it would help me SO much.

I did try myself on some coding, but I am no coder and I am not sure if it would be helpful at all to share my failure  But this is what I've tried so far:

```
function Loop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var EndRow = ss.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 2; i <= EndRow; i++) {
    var Day = ss.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var Consultants = ss.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    var Off = ss.getRange(i,7).getValue ();
    var Count = ss.getRange(i,8).getValue();

    if(Day == Off){
      ss.getRange(i, 3).setValue(Consultants)
    }else{
      ss.getRange(i, 3).setValue(Consultants)
    }
  }
  }
```

EDIT:

I found a way without using apps scripts, costs me some more work manually and first tried it with a shorter team list.
The highlighted yellow cells are the cells in which the day off was identical to the work-day cell. So they got switched.
I did have to copy paste my input list of consultants but if this is the only manual way, its fine :)
[image: Formula]

Comment: Your best chance of getting an answer for a problem like this is to provide the sheet information in a form so that we can copy and paste it.  It's a fairly easy solution but personally I would not bother with it if I have to rewrite the entire sheet manually.  You could try posting a link to your sheet and some volunteers with take that bait and they will expose their email to you but I won't.

Comment: Hi @Cooper , thanks! I added a link to the published spreadsheet so there is no need to login.

Comment: Apologies but the example you've provided is not enough for me to understand the logic of your problem. Kindly show us how you map the data manually and provide more example.

Comment: Screenshot added for manual outcome. I want to make sure that no co-worker will be added to the schedule on a day that they do not work. 
If I'd had to do this for 100+ coworkers and growing, it would cost me a lot of manual work to go through this, especially when people come and go very often or change their working hours.

Comment: [Edit] to show your current attempt.  Ask a [programming question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/) and not to implement a feature

Comment: @TheMaster in my original post I had it added but people got angry for me not being a professional coder ;)

Comment: @Cooper The published link posted by OP won't show up in your Google drive(in case you didn't know)

Comment: How do I know that by looking at it?

Comment: @Cooper The published url is always of this format: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/{PUB_ID}/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true` It can't even be traced back to the original spreadsheet id, AFAIK.

Comment: @TheMaster That's a good was to get a copy of the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this:

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var dayCol = sh.getRange("B2:B343").getValues().flat(); //get day column values and convert it to 1d array
  var dayOffCol = sh.getRange("G2:G9").getValues().flat(); //get day off values and convert it to 1d array
  var dayOffColCopy; //initialize copy 
  var consCol = sh.getRange("F2:F9").getValues().flat(); //get consultants values or column F
  var consColCopy; //initialize copy
  var tempArray = []; //storage of final value for column C
  for(var i = 0; i < dayCol.length; i++){  //loop through dayCol values
    var ctr = (i % consCol.length); //used modulo as counter. the value will return to 0 if the value of i is divisible to the length of consCol or in example 8

    //The if statement below will help up reset the value of
    //consColCopy and dayOffColCopy once the values are emptied because of the splice()
    if(ctr == 0){ 
      consColCopy = consCol.slice();
      dayOffColCopy = dayOffCol.slice();
    }
    
    //the loop below will get the first non-matching values of dayCol and dayOffColCopy,
    //the first non-matching values will be removed to the copy variables using splice() 
    //and insert it to tempArray using push()
    for(var j = 0; j < dayOffColCopy.length; j++){ //loop through dayOffColCopy values
      if(dayCol[i] != dayOffColCopy[j]){ 
        tempArray.push(consColCopy.splice(j, 1)); 
        dayOffColCopy.splice(j, 1);
        break; //exit loop
      }      
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2, 3, tempArray.length, 1).setValues(tempArray); //set the values of temp array to column C
}
```

**Example Data & Output:**

[image]

***Note:** Make sure to use the cell that has data in your range and change the sheet name. I also added comments in my code to explain the process.*

### References:

- [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)